# Power button triggers a ctrl+alt+deleter screen

Tags: windows-8.1, sleep, power, ctrl-alt-delete

I have looked up for a solution on several forums but can't find it, hope I didn't miss it !
I have a laptop and I am used to turn it into sleeping mode by pressing the physical power button that is on the right of the laptop. But for a few days this button is acting as if I pressed ctrl+alt+delete (same screen with lock computer / switch user etc.). 
I have checked the parameters in the control panel / choose what the power buttons do and they are correct : sleeping mode ! I can change it but it doesn't change anything.
I have checked in the control panel / power option / change advanced power settings : everything seems to be OK and if I change it nothing change for real.

I can't remember changing anything this precise day or the day before it happened...

Does anybody have an idea ?

Don't hesitate if you want anymore information

Thank you for reading and for your answer :)

Vincent

PS : my laptop is a Sony / vaio duo pro SVD1121X9EB with windows 8.1 Pro (64bit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your User profile is corrupted,I had the same thing,here is the fix,

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/fix-corrupted-user-profile#1TC=windows-7

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.